# Reading a zlog (c logging library) log file with "tail -f" makes program run 4x faster

Tags: c, freeradius

I have a bit of a strange problem with `zlog`. Let me just describe the application first. It's a freeradius module written in c which uses `zlog` as a logging library. The system is Linux mint 17.3 x64, ext4, kernel 3.19.0.

Now when I use command `tail -f log.log` on the log file while the program is running, the program starts to run 4x faster. When monitoring I also notice a lot bigger processor usage on freeradius + of course on the bash terminal where `tail` is ran. There is about 16.000 log writes per second, when tail is running.

There is nothing fancy happening in the source code, just the standard:

```
zlog_get_category(...);
zlog_debug(zc, "....");
```

etc.

So the question is, what could be the cause of this behaviour, it seems very unusual, if anything running freeradius with tail running at the same time should be slower?

Comment: This seems like a nice opportunity to learn and test out [bpftrace](https://www.joyfulbikeshedding.com/blog/2019-01-31-full-system-dynamic-tracing-on-linux-using-ebpf-and-bpftrace.html). I have no experience myself, but would assume this is the right tool to attack this with.